How to send email from company information email address in netsuite suitescript?
I have created user event script to send email. I want to send email from company enformation email address, but I am getting error as,

{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_AUTHOR_MUST_BE_EMPLOYEE","message":"The author internal id or email must match an employee.","id":"","stack":["doSendEmail(N/email)","afterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/emailsend.js:20)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"SSS_AUTHOR_MUST_BE_EMPLOYEE","details":"The author internal id or email must match an employee.","userEvent":"aftersubmit","stackTrace":["doSendEmail(N/email)","afterSubmit(/SuiteScripts/emailsend.js:20)"],"notifyOff":false},"notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}

Below is my code:
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/email', 'N/log'], function(email, log) {

    function afterSubmit(context) {
        try {
            // Get the current record
            var newRecord = context.newRecord;

        
            var emailAddress = 'customer@xyz.com'

       
            var name = "oracle netsuite"

            // Send email
            email.send({
                author: 'companyinformation@xyz.com', // or any other internal id
                recipients: emailAddress,
                subject: 'Example Subject',
                body: 'Dear ' + name + ',\n\nThis is an example email sent from SuiteScript.',
            });

            log.debug('Email Sent', 'An email has been sent to ' + emailAddress);

        } catch (e) {
            log.error('Error Sending Email', e);
        }
    }

    return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };

});

Is there any way to work this?

"The author internal id or email must match an employee." - So is the e-mail provided a known employee?

No email is not provided to any employee

Why not? Looking at the error message returned this is a requirement

Client is not allowing and providing employee to set email address

Consider creating a "fake" employee in the system and use the assigned email to make this work?

You cannot send email from NetSuite using an arbitrary sender email. The author parameter of email.send must be a numeric internal ID of an active Employee record.
Your client should create an Employee record dedicated to this purpose and give it the desired email address, then your script can use the internal ID of the new record as the author.
Many companies make a generic "No Reply" Employee. The Employee does not need login access and so does not need to consume a license.

I found solution to this on suiteanswers:
https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22315/loc/en_US
or you can add that emial id on company set preferences and that email will get assigned to the current user.
